# <embed?> element not able to show pdf preview on safari

Tags: javascript, html, django, safari

My embed element is able to show pdf preview in chrome but not in safari. Can anyone advise on how I can render the embed PDF Preview element on safari?

I have tried some of the methods but none worked.

[Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html)

Thank you!

```
<embed src="" type="application/pdf">
```

Answer (score 1):

In many mobile browsers, PDFs are not able to be rendered using standard embeds, instead, you might want to turn to a library such as [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) by Mozilla. This library renders pdfs independently of the built-in PDF viewer, so it doesn't have the same restrictions as embeds.